# Isolated singularities sort

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me out with finding the nature of the singularities of the following function:

$$g(z)=\frac{\cos z-1}{z^5}$$ without using Taylor expansions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to figure out the nature of the singularity $z_0=0$. Write $p(z)=\cos(z)-1$ and $q(z)=z^5$. Then $g(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$. Notice that $z_0$ is a zero of order $2$ for $p$ and a zero of order $5$ for $q$. Then you must have seen a theorem that states that $z_0$ is then a pole of order $5-2=3$.

Otherwise, write $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^3}f(z)$ with $f(z)=\frac{\cos(z)-1}{z^2}$. Use Hospital's rule to compute that $f(z_0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ and notice that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Then take its Taylor series and multiply by $\frac{1}{z^3}$ to find the Laurent series of $g$. I let you compute its residue at $z_0$.

Comment: The question explicitly states "*...without using Taylor expansions*".

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected a mistake. I wrote that the order of $z_0$ for $p$ was $3$ and actually meant $2$. @FlybyNight I know, it was just in case he had not seen in class the result I mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: Can you formulate the theorem you used in the first paragraph?

Comment: Sure. Let $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are functions that are holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. Let $z_0$ be a zero of order $k$ of $p$, i.e., $p(z_0)=\ldots=p^{(k-1)}(z_0)=0$ but $p^{(k)}(z_0)\neq 0$ (if $p(z_0)\neq 0$, then set $k=0$). Let $z_0$ be a zero of order $l$ of $q$, i.e., $q(z_0)=\ldots=q^{(l-1)}(z_0)=0$ but $q^{(l)}(z_0)\neq 0$ (if $q(z_0)\neq 0$, then set $l=0$). Now, if $l>k$, then $z_0$ is a pole of order $l-k$ of $f$. If $l\leq k$, then $z_0$ is a regular point of $f$ (where $f(z_0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$).

Answer (score 4):

[Since](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)
$$\lim_{z\to0}z^4g(z)=0$$
then $0$ is a pole of $g$ with order $3$.

Comment: Fond of short and straightforward hint. +1